# Bootloop - can get to Fastboot, but volume buttons just restart the phone

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, boot-loop, google-pixel-3-xl

Pixel 3 XL - has worked like a champ for years, but just started bootlooping. If I hold vol down + power, I can get into fastboot. However, volume down and volume up buttons don't let me navigate. Either one of those just restarts the phone. I don't believe there is any physical issue with the volume buttons since they've always worked perfet. If I let the phone just sit in FASTBOOT mode, after about 5 seconds it restarts and starts looping again.

I needed a phone right away, so I found another used Pixel 3 XL, and I'm using that now. I'd love to get the old one booting again so I can sell it, or at the very least, ensure that I do a factory reset on it before bringing to a recycler.

Any ideas how I can get out of FASTBOOT mode or securely delete my data?

Comment: buttons stuck/wet/short-circuited

Comment: @alecxs I don't think so since they both do something (restart the phone) when clicked.

Comment: can power off phone and does it stay off?

Comment: The phone would not power off. It just kept rebooting until dead.

Comment: if you press and keep holding power button this would have same effect on any device. I think your buttons dried meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this phone working again by unplugging from the wall and letting it continue bootlooping until the battery was dead. I then let it sit for a day to ensure it had no power left. I then charged via USB on my PC (NOT A WALL CHARGER) until it was fully charged. I then powered it up and it seems to be working okay so far.